# logic issue with spitting out data, variables being repeated

Tags: javascript, jquery, logic

I am trying to parse out a table that has customers vertically and time stamps horizontally. what I have so far does this but repeats the time stamps from previous customers with each loop. Here is my code:

```
json = JSON.parse(xmlHTTP.responseText);
    message = "<table><tr id='head_table'><td>Name:</td><td>Rnd 1:</td><td>Rnd 2:</td><td>Rnd 3:</td><td>Rnd 4:</td><td>Rnd 5:</td><td>Rnd 6:</td><td>Options:</td></tr>";
    for(var i=0; i<json.collection.length; i++)
    {
        message = message + "<tr><td>" + json.collection[i].customer.name + "</td>";

        for(var j=0; j<json.collection[i].events.length; j++)
        {
            eventmsg = eventmsg + "<td>" + json.collection[i].events[j].time_stamp + "</td>";
        }
        message = message + eventmsg + "</tr>";
    }
    message = message + "</table>";
```

The JSON looks like this:

```
- collection: [
   - {
      - customer: {
          id: "1",
          name: "Mr Jones",
          customer_id: "1"
        }
      -events: [
         -{
           event_id: "1",
           time_stamp: "1377083342"
          }
         -{
           event_id: "2",
           time_stamp: "1377083342"
          }
```

Comment: Please post your JSON, at least a few rows' worth.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see no errors here try this .. if it does not work past part of the json.

```
var json = JSON.parse(xmlHTTP.responseText),
message = "<table><tr id='head_table'><td>Name:</td><td>Rnd 1:</td><td>Rnd 2:</td><td>Rnd 3:</td><td>Rnd 4:</td><td>Rnd 5:</td><td>Rnd 6:</td><td>Options:</td></tr>";

for(var i=0; i<json.collection.length; i++){
 message+="<tr><td>" + json.collection[i].customer.name + "</td>";
 for(var j=0; j<json.collection[i].events.length; j++){
  message+="<td>" + json.collection[i].events[j].time_stamp + "</td>";
 }
 message+="</tr>";
}
message+="</table>";
```

you don't need to write `msg=msg+evntmsg` it's confusing and leads to errors
also you don't need another var for events one is enough as you just append

so `msg+=newstring`

think o it as you just append a string.

tip.: cache your json.

```
var collection = JSON.parse(xmlHTTP.responseText).collection

for(var i=0 , co ; co = collection[i] ; ++i){
 message+="<tr><td>" + co.customer.name + "</td>";
 for(var j=0 , ev ; ev = co.events[j] ; ++j){
  message+="<td>" + ev.time_stamp + "</td>";
 }
 message+="</tr>";
}
message+="</table>";
```